# Monthly Logins Used is Double Counting Logins to OAuth enabled site

Tags: apex, community, customer-community

We are using "Partner Community Login" licenses and Salesforce Communities as our Single Sign On solution for an external web portal (not based on Communities).

Each time a user logs in, it is counting as 2 logins against our Monthly Logins Used quota (once for logging into Salesforce, and then again when our site uses OAuth to request their identity information)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Log a case to support. SSO is setup correctly?

Comment: Whenever user tries to login , the login history get two records one for remote access2.0 and second for chatter communities external user. Why is it so>?